# Index multiple relationships polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am wondering if its possible to do the following

I have many articles, and
I have many photos.

I am trying to show all article and all the set of photos belonging to the article. To me in the controller I wanna do the following

```
@mosttop = Article.all[1..-1]
@loc = @mosttop.photos
```

Comment: `to show all article and all the set of photos belonging to the article` <= This does not make sense. What is `the article` if you have all articles ?

Comment: Well I want to show All Article like an Index action would. In my case I actually use mosttop = Article.all[1..-1] so its not all of them. Then I wanted to see all picture in the index folder by merging @mosttop.photos which his associated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a set of `articles`. You use `Article.all[1..-1]` for some reason so I'll stick with it.
Then you want every `photos` of each `articles` merged into one set of `photos` ?

Since you use `Rails`, you can use [`flat_map`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map)

```
@articles = Article.all[1..-1]
@photos = @articles.flat_map(&:photos)

@photos.each do |photo|
  # show photo
end
```

Comment: Using the `flat_map` method would cause an N+1 SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Answer (score 1):

```
# app/models/article.rb
has_many :photos

# app/models/photo.rb
belongs_to :article

# app/controllers/article_controller.rb
def index
  @articles = Article.include(:photos).all
end

# app/views/articles/index.html.erb
<%= render :partial => "articles/article_with_photos", :collection => @articles

# app/views/articles/_article_with_phots.html.erb
<H2><%= article.title %></H2>
Photos
<ul>
  <% article.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <li><%= image_tag(photo.url) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```